# How can I download the statistics (or time series) of Facebook messages exchanged between myself and my significant other?

Tags: messenger

I have tried searching for a way to download some basic stats, or even a time series plot, that tallies the amount of facebook messenger activity between myself and my significant other. This is a much needed step to expedite some paperwork we need for a government application. Scrolling through a multi-year history and counting which days we used Messenger seems tortuous. Even if there was a way to download a vector of timestamps of messages between us, that would help a lot. I could code my own plot for the paperwork. Some blogs have mentioned using the "download a copy of your facebook data" from the support inbox, but I do not see that link on the appropriate page anymore. Does anyone know where it moved to?

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure this is the right forum for this question

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but hopefully it works:

Go to your settings (the little downward pointing arrow, then choose settings),and right below all the options within the main box there should be a message saying "Download a copy of your Facebook data.", click the link, start the archive and *apparently* it should work. But whether or not it has timestamps and such, is a mystery for me (but likely).

edit: If this does not work, depending on your computer/volume of messages, what you could also do is open the mobile browser messenger (to reduce processing power needed), and start scrolling up within your conversation right up until to the top, then ctrl+a and copy everything to a word document. But obviously this would not work for conversations in the multiple thousand message territory